# Function of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, functions

Random variable X have a density of distribution

[image]

Density of a random variable $Y = 1-X^2$

I started solving this, but I'm not sure is my solution correct and if not where is my mistake?

$$
F_Y(y) = P(Y<y)=P(1-X^2<y)=P(X^2>1-y)=P(X>\sqrt{1-y})= 1 - P(X<\sqrt{1-y})=1-\int^{\sqrt{1-y}}_{-1}\frac{x+1}{2}dx
$$

Is this correct so far? Then i just integrate to obtain $F_Y(x)$ and then find Differential  to get $p_y(x)$

Comment: No because $X^2$ can exceed $1-y$ even for negative realizations of $X$ and you're not accounting for that.

Comment: Can you post the solution or partial solution anyway? I forget to write Y, can you check if that part is correct again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F_Y(y) = P(Y<y)=P(1-X^2<y)=P(X^2>1-y)=P(X>\sqrt{1-y})+P(X<-\sqrt{1-y})= 1 - P(X<\sqrt{1-y})+P(X<-\sqrt{1-y})=1-\int^{\sqrt{1-y}}_{-1}\frac{x+1}{2}dx+\int^{-\sqrt{1-y}}_{-1}\frac{x+1}{2}dx$